# Replace / Add Toolchain in Xcode

Tags: xcode, toolchain

I would like to either replace the toolchain within XCode (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain) or even add another one from older Xcode versions. Is there an easy way to do so? I only found some methods how to add Swift Toolchains for newer Xcode 7.3. I'm running on 7.3 and would like to use Toolchain from 6.x or even earlier.

Answer (score 0):

- Get a toolchain from previous Xcode version from `Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Frameworks/Toolchains/`
- Copy it to `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains`.
- Open Xcode, settings > components > Toolchains tab; select the required toolchain.

Comment: It says "The toolchain is not compatible with this version of Xcode." Tried with Xcode 14.3 beta and toolchain of Xcode 14.2

Comment: My Settings window doesn't have a Components tab. Running Xcode 14.3.1. Was it moved?